# GWT styles not applying

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm creating a **GWT** application that uses **UiBinder**, and I've come across a bizarre problem where styles aren't applying to my elements--until I refresh the browser, and then the styles briefly get applied, in that fraction of a second before the page refreshes.  In other words:

1. Open page; none of my defined styles are used.
2. Hit Refresh
3. For a fraction of a second the styles are used, before the page goes blank
4. The page reloads, without the styles again

I'm going to include my entire `*ui.xml` file, because it's not too big.

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <ui:style>
        .idLabelStyle {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .nameLabelStyle {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            width: 500px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .addressLabelStyle {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            width: 500px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
        }
    </ui:style>
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <g:HorizontalPanel>
            <g:Label addStyleNames="{style.idLabelStyle}">ID</g:Label>
            <g:Label addStyleNames="{style.nameLabelStyle}">Name</g:Label>
            <g:Label addStyleNames="{style.addressLabelStyle}">Address</g:Label>
        </g:HorizontalPanel>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

I really hope I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `addStyleNames=` use `setStyleName=` or `setStylePrimaryName=` I have had this issue in the past and it fixed it in my case. 
Note: the two possiblities are indicated below...

```
setStyleName
Clears all of the object's style names and sets it to the given style. You should normally use setStylePrimaryName(String) unless you wish to explicitly remove all existing styles.

setStylePrimaryName
Sets the object's primary style name and updates all dependent style names.
```

Comment: Thanks Romain.  Still no luck, though.  I'm getting the same result as before.

    <g:Label stylePrimaryName="{style.idLabelStyle}">ID</g:Label>

and

    <g:Label styleName="{style.idLabelStyle}">ID</g:Label>

are both giving me the same results.

Comment: try
<g:Label styleName='{style.idLabelStyle}'>ID</g:Label>

Comment: `styleName="..."` is correct, GWT translates this to `setStyleName` behind the scenes.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, I tried using `styleName` and it still didn't work.

Comment: Do you have any other style sheets in your project ?
Do you have any styles in your html files or even in your GWT code ?

Comment: Only the main, default stylesheet supplied by GWT (which I haven't yet emptied).  None of the styles overlap, though, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately or unfortunately, I'm no longer using this widget in my app; however, I didn't want to lose the code, because this problem was driving me nuts and I wanted to know what I was missing.

Unfortunately, after changing my code around, and then re-adding the widget to test it, I can't reproduce the problem anymore.

It might be the way I'm adding the widget to my UI; I don't remember how I was originally adding it (it was too many changes ago), but I'm now adding it to a `VerticalPanel` by using the `add(Widget)` method, and the styles are now applying with no problem.

Thanks to the commenters who followed me on my wild goose chase. I wish I had a more satisfactory answer...

Comment: Did some more research and ...
The problem is that GWT obfuscates the styles.

See http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/dde31397ef4914a1/9e27674998a20645

Comment: GWT does obfuscate the styles, but as long as you use the format above, you're fine.  i.e. `addStyleNames="{style.idLabelStyle}"` - notice the curly braces, and the fact that we're qualifying the name of the style with the `style.` prefix.  When GWT compiles this code, they'll use the obfuscated names under the covers, but our code can use the names we define.

Answer (score 0):

When using Cell based panels in UiBinder; wrap child elements in  tags and set their alignments and sizes individually.

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CellPanel.html